# Is there an easy way to aggregate disk usage by file type in a directory?

Tags: linux, du

I have a folder, which contains 10 folders, which contain a huge mess of files.  I'd like to see, not which files specifically are using the most, but which kinds of files (.png, .jpg, .txt etc.) are using the most disk space.  I saw a previous post that listed the disk usage of a file type by giving the extension, but I want to show it for all extensions that exist in my file set, which makes it difficult to do.

This is on a bog-standard Debian installation, and I do not have permission to install new utilities.

Bonus points if it can be run from the folder containing 10 folders and show it for all 10.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Weird, I could've sworn I talked about some of the research I did for my question. Must've been my imagination. Funny that the topic you linked was in response to people doing exactly what you did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the most optimized way but should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ext in `find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u`; do
    echo $ext": "`find . -name "*."$ext -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -1`
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  I realized that my files, for some reason, had the file type before a number (format: filename.extension.somerandomnumber), so I had to adjust the perl regex to match that instead, but my request was met perfectly and it was easy to change.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kwahn, glad it worked! thanks to you I never thought of checking/cleaning up by file types!